# Reactive Vue Chart.js component using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-class-components

Using [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) (or actually its `Component` and `Prop` of [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)) and [vue-chartjs-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs-typescript), I am trying to make a `BarChart`-component with the properties `chartData` and `options`. The following code actually works when serving the app:

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs-typescript'
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  const { reactiveProp } = mixins

  @Component({
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
  })
  export default class BarChart extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    chartData: any

    @Prop({default: function () { return {} }})
    options!: object

    mounted() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, it fails when building the app. Also my IDE (PyCharm Pro) gives the same error:

> TS2339: Property 'renderChart' does not exist on type 'BarChart'.

So when using the `@Component({extends: Bar})`, for the interpreter it is not clear that this component extends `Bar`. I've already tried to extend `Bar` instead of `Vue`, so `export default class BarChart extends Bar`. But that gives the following error:

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly define the function you want to use inside the class `BarChart`

```
  public renderChart!: (chartData: any, options: any) => void
```